# Incorrect string value: '\xD6\xD0\xB9\xFA\xB1\xEA...' for column 'VARIABLE_VALUE' at row 1

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-cms

### Heading ##I want to learn django-cms.  so insatall it.

the Requirements have installed

**python manage.py runserver  ok**
0 errors found
January 04, 2014 - 16:19:19
Django version 1.5.5, using settings 'mycms.settings'
Development server is running at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

**but python manage.py runserver syncdb --all (The first time I've used django-cms)

The error occurred**
Screen displays Syncing...
Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xD6\xD0\xB9\xFA\xB1\xEA...' for column 'VARIABLE_VALUE' 
at row 1

---

mysql  version  5.1   The database encoding is utf-8
django 1.5.5
python 2.7.6
Mysql-python 1.2.3

---

I don't know why will happen this error

Comment: Do not duplicate your questions. please edit your original question and add there any clarification that could be needed. This question is probably being closed as duplicated

Answer (score 0):

Each table column has Collation attribute. You set that variable to utf-8.

Comment: Put the mysql5.1 to 5.5.  The problem is ok.I don't know why